# php display blank and error on mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php

I receive a blank page when I try connect to mysql, based on the error. php doesn't like the 3rd line

```
$link = "SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `id`='$id'";
$results = mysqli_query($db,$link);
$qdata = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
```

This code is working on my old server, so `mysqli_fetch_array` seems absolute? Or did I miss something else on my php config?

Thanks!

This is the error message
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /opt/php_script/connect.php on line 14`

Line 14 is

```
$link = "SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `id`='$id'";
```

Comment: Edit your question to include your error message.

Comment: Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the script to see error messages instead of a blank page.  This should help solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mysqli` extendion is not enabled. Check your `php.ini`, go to the extensions part and enable it.

Answer (score 2):

This means the build of PHP you are using does not have `mysqli` support.  You will have to recompile PHP with mysqli support (on Linux) or add the `php_mysqli.dll` extension to your `php.ini` file on Windows.

See [Installation - mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) on PHP.net for more information.